GeoServer: cannot create new styles in GeoServer deployed in Kubernetes
After deploying the kartoza/geoserver docker image to Kubernetes, most functionality works as expected. However when trying to add or edit a style, the request fails with http error 403. The GeoServer deploy sits behind an NGINX ingress. As I said, all the other functionality on the GeoServer deploy works. What is special about the style creation and editing process that would cause it to fail?
Here is the request that fails:
https://myhost.org/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.wms.web.data.StyleNewPage?9-2.IBehaviorListener.0-save&wicket-ajax=true&wicket-ajax-baseurl=wicket%2Fbookmarkable%2Forg.geoserver.wms.web.data.StyleNewPage%3F9
I have set DEBUG logging and now I get these messages:
2024-08-08 14:56:11,727 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.wms.web.data.stylepage, QueryString: filter=false'; against '/web/**'

2024-08-08 14:56:11,727 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.wms.web.data.stylepage, QueryString: filter=false with /web/**
2024-08-08 14:56:11,728 DEBUG [geoserver.monitor] - Testing /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.wms.web.data.StylePage for monitor filtering
2024-08-08 14:56:11,728 DEBUG [geoserver.monitor] - /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.wms.web.data.StylePage was filtered from monitoring
2024-08-08 14:56:11,730 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2024-08-08 14:56:11,730 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2024-08-08 14:56:11,730 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2024-08-08 14:56:11,730 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2024-08-08 14:56:11,730 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2024-08-08 14:56:11,731 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 30836 locking in mode READ
2024-08-08 14:56:11,731 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 30836 got the lock in mode READ
2024-08-08 14:56:11,794 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 30836 locking in mode READ
2024-08-08 14:56:11,794 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 30836 releasing the lock in mode READ
2024-08-08 14:56:11,796 DEBUG [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2024-08-08 14:56:11,832 DEBUG
Here are the volume mount specs:
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: web-context-script
      configMap:
        name: web-context-script
        defaultMode: 511
    - name: web-config-script
      configMap:
        name: web-config-script
        defaultMode: 511
    - name: geoserver-data-dir
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: apsviz-geoserver-pvc
    - name: geowebcache-cache-dir
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: apsviz-geoserver-dev-geoserver-cache-dir
  containers:
    - name: apsviz-geoserver-dev-geoserver
      image: docker.io/kartoza/geoserver:2.20.1
      ports:
        - name: http-geoserver
          containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
      env:
        - name: PROXY_BASE_URL
          value: https://<FQDN/geoserver
        - name: GEOSERVER_ADMIN_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: apsviz-geoserver-dev-geoserver
              key: geoserver-user
        - name: GEOSERVER_ADMIN_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: apsviz-geoserver-dev-geoserver
              key: geoserver-password
        - name: COMMUNITY_EXTENSIONS
          value: >-
            mbtiles-plugin,mbtiles-store-plugin,cog-plugin,ncwms-plugin,s3-geotiff-plugin
        - name: STABLE_EXTENSIONS
          value: importer-plugin
      resources:
        limits:
          ephemeral-storage: 512Mi
          memory: 16Gi
        requests:
          cpu: '1'
          ephemeral-storage: 64Mi
          memory: 5Gi
      volumeMounts:
        - name: web-context-script
          mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/conf/context.xml
          subPath: context.xml
        - name: web-config-script
          mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml
          subPath: web.xml
        - name: geoserver-data-dir
          mountPath: /opt/geoserver/data_dir
        - name: geowebcache-cache-dir
          mountPath: /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc
          subPath: gwc
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      securityContext:
        capabilities:
          drop:
            - NET_RAW
        allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
  restartPolicy: Always
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  serviceAccountName: default
  serviceAccount: default
  nodeName: k8s-node09
  securityContext:
    seccompProfile:
      type: RuntimeDefault
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: image-pull-secret
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  tolerations:
    - key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
      operator: Exists
      effect: NoExecute
      tolerationSeconds: 300
    - key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
      operator: Exists
      effect: NoExecute
      tolerationSeconds: 300
  priority: 0
  enableServiceLinks: true
  preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority


How is your data directory mounted to the container, what are the permissions of the styes directory? What are the relevant lines in the log file, when it fails?

Hello Ian. Thanks for responding!
I added the spec for the volume mounts to the original question.
The permission for the styles dir was ...
drwxr-x---.     3 geoserveruser geoserverusers   12288 Aug  7 21:04 styles
so I changed it to:
drwxrwxrwx.   3 geoserveruser geoserverusers   12288 Aug  7 21:04 styles
... and restarted the pod. Still the same problem.

There is no other relevant info in the geoserver log.
Here are some errors from the browser console: POST https://apsviz-geoserver-dev.apps.renci.org/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.wms.web.data.StyleNewPage?8-3.IBehaviorListener.0-save&wicket-ajax=true&wicket-ajax-baseurl=wicket%2Fbookmarkable%2Forg.geoserver.wms.web.data.StyleNewPage%3F8 403 (Forbidden) wicket-ajax-jquery-ver-693964C770553710C590B40E6EAFB309.js:138 Wicket.Ajax:  Wicket.Ajax.Call.failure: Error while parsing response: Could not find root <ajax-response> element'

There will always be relevant lines in the log if need be you need to turn up the logging level.

Ian I turned the geoserver logging level to DEBUG and only got the logging I posted in the original question above.
